# Symfony2: Doctrine is not returning Collection from DB on OneToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony-2.4

I'm having an issue with one relationship in my system. I'm pretty sure I'm doing this correctly and that I have a bug in the code I can't see.

I've pasted my class below. Basically when I do fighter.getFighterAttributes() i get a null array. It does not happen with the other relationships in the class. Furthermore when I look at the logs I see that the other relationships are being called but not FighterAttributes().

The table has entries that have been inserted using the entity.

It has to be a BUG IN MY CODE, not sure were though :(

Below Class and logs.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AppBundle\Repository\FighterRepository")
 */
class Fighter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $firstName;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contract", mappedBy="fighter")
     */
    protected $contracts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bout", mappedBy="fighters")
     */
    protected $bouts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FighterAttribute", mappedBy="fighter")
     */
    protected $fighterAttributes;

// Custom ------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set createDT
     */
    public function setCreateDT()
    {
        $this->createDT = new \DateTime("now");
    }

// Automated ---------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return Fighter
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }


    /**
     * Add bouts
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Bout $bouts
     * @return Fighter
     */
    public function addBout(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Bout $bouts)
    {
        $this->bouts[] = $bouts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bouts
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Bout $bouts
     */
    public function removeBout(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Bout $bouts)
    {
        $this->bouts->removeElement($bouts);
    }

    /**
     * Get bouts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getBouts()
    {
        return $this->bouts;
    }

    /**
     * Add contracts
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Contract $contracts
     * @return Fighter
     */
    public function addContract(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Contract $contracts)
    {
        $this->contracts[] = $contracts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove contracts
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Contract $contracts
     */
    public function removeContract(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Contract $contracts)
    {
        $this->contracts->removeElement($contracts);
    }

    /**
     * Get contracts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getContracts()
    {
        return $this->contracts;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contracts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->bouts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->fighterAttributes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->setCreateDT();
    }


    /**
     * Add fighterAttributes
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute $fighterAttributes
     * @return Fighter
     */
    public function addFighterAttribute(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute $fighterAttributes)
    {
        $this->fighterAttributes[] = $fighterAttributes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove fighterAttributes
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute $fighterAttributes
     */
    public function removeFighterAttribute(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute $fighterAttributes)
    {
        $this->fighterAttributes->removeElement($fighterAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Get fighterAttributes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getFighterAttributes()
    {
        return $this->fighterAttributes;
    }
}
```

Log Below:

```
[2014-02-14 01:36:13] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT ... FROM Fighter t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 ["110"] []
[2014-02-14 01:36:13] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT ... FROM Contract t0 WHERE t0.fighter_id = ? [110] []
[2014-02-14 01:36:13] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT ... FROM Bout t0 INNER JOIN BoutFighter ON t0.id = BoutFighter.bout_id WHERE BoutFighter.fighter_id = ? [110] []
```

Note that there is no entry for FighterAttribute.

Class FighterAttribute below:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FighterAttribute
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fighter", inversedBy="fighterAttributes")
     */
    protected $fighter;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Attribute")
     */
    protected $attribute;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fighter
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Fighter $fighter
     * @return FighterAttribute
     */
    public function setFighter(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Fighter $fighter = null)
    {
        $this->fighter = $fighter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fighter
     *
     * @return \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Fighter 
     */
    public function getFighter()
    {
        return $this->fighter;
    }

    /**
     * Set attribute
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Attribute $attribute
     * @return FighterAttribute
     */
    public function setAttribute(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Attribute $attribute = null)
    {
        $this->attribute = $attribute;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute
     *
     * @return \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Attribute 
     */
    public function getAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attribute;
    }

    /**
     * Set amount
     *
     * @param integer $amount
     * @return FighterAttribute
     */
    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amount
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

**Update**

This code prints "null"

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $fighter = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Fighter')
            ->findOneById($fighter_id);

        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($fighter->getFighterAttributes(), 1);
        die();
```

This code prints the fighterAttributes:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $fighter = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Fighter')
            ->findOneById($fighter_id);

        $attributes = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:FighterAttribute')
            ->findByFighter($fighter);

        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($attributes, 1);
        die();
```

OutPut:

```
array (size=12) 0 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 1 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 2 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 3 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 4 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 5 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 6 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 7 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 8 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 9 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 10 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 11 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38)
```

This code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $fighter = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Fighter')
            ->findOneById($fighter_id);

        $attributes = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:FighterAttribute')
            ->findByFighter($fighter);

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
        {
            $fighter->addFighterAttribute($attribute);
        }

        $em->persist($fighter);
        $em->flush();

        $fighter1 = $em->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:Fighter')
            ->findOneById($fighter_id);

        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($fighter1->getFighterAttributes(), 1);
        die();
```

Output:

```
array (size=12) 0 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 1 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 2 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 3 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 4 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 5 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 6 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 7 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 8 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 9 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 10 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38) 11 => string 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\FighterAttribute' (length=38)
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I found the issue. It was the caching setting I had been playing with that was bringing me all sort of issues.

I was seeing that even though I updated some object the app was behaving erratically and not recognizing some of the changes. Even I had cleared the app cache several times, it was that APC cache that needed clearing.

I decided for now to just disable it since I'm still in dev, but I would assume clearing the APC cache would have resolved the issue as well. In config_dev.yml i commented the following:

```
#doctrine:
#    orm:
#        metadata_cache_driver: apc
#        result_cache_driver: apc
#        query_cache_driver: apc
```

@Patt, appreciate your help and working through your solution helped me figured it out, but the code change you suggested didn't add value after I performed this change. As I suspected there is no need to update the non-owning side of the relationship unless there is plans to use it then or do some type of cascading persistance which I'm not.